# Get all elements in an array inside of a document that have a date greater than now in mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection called FilmSessions and each FilmSession document has a property called seats

```
{
'filmName': 'string',
'seats': Seat[]
}
 // example with data
{
'filmName': 'Batman',
'seats': [
    {
      'state': 'available',
      'seatNumber': 1
   },{
      'state': 'available',
      'seatNumber': 2
   }
 ]
}
```

an example of a seat that is not reserved

```
{
 'state': 'available',
'seatNumber': 1
}
```

once the customer selects and the seat is reserved and the customer needs to pay

```
{
 'state': 'reserved',
 'reservedAt': DATE
 'seatNumber': 1
}
```

and once the customer has paid the seat , the seat goes to paid

```
{
 'state': 'paid',
 'paidAt': DATE
 'seatNumber': 1
}
```

I want to get all FilmSessions with at least one seat state set to reserved, with the field reservedAt existing and that has been expired (that 15 min had past since it was set to reservedAt ,this means that the customer didn't buy the seat and we can make it available )

When getting the FilmSessions that have at least one seat reserved . I want to get all the sets not just the reserved ones

Im using mongodb and I cant change the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the FilmSession documents where **at least one seat is reserved** and to **only** get the seats which are reserved, where the `reservedAt` timestamp is of **older than 15 mins ago**, you can write the following query using the mongodb driver in nodejs:

```
db.collection("FilmSessions").find({
  "seats.state": "reserved",
  "seats.reservedAt": {
    $lt: new Date(Date.now() - (1000*60*15))
  }
},
{
  "filmName": 1,
  "seats": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "reservedAt": {
          $lt: new Date(Date.now() - (1000*60*15))
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a [link to MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BA4YZhk9ohH) where you can get an idea of this (The timestamp calculated above is hardcoded in the MongoPlayground sample, but should give you an idea of how the query works).

Answer (score 0):

- Remove 15 minutes from current date and check condition `reservedAt` date is less than input date

```
let reservedAt = new Date();
reservedAt.setMinutes(reservedAt.getMinutes() - 15);

db.collection.find({
  "seats.reservedAt": {
    $lt: reservedAt
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m3zPCJsXK56)